# How to remove notification when click on notification android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

Can i remove this notification in a click on notication?

I can cancel notification when click on this notification using the setAutoCancel(true).

but not clear notification after click on notification.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg, Bundle extras) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent;
    if (extras != null) {
        intent = new Intent(this, MessageConversationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sender_id", extras.get("sender_id").toString());
        intent.putExtra("receiver_id", Application.ACTIVE_USER.getUser_id());
        intent.putExtra("gender", extras.get("gender").toString());
        intent.putExtra("profile_picture", extras.get("profile_picture")
                .toString());
        intent.putExtra("username", extras.get("username").toString());
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    String app_name = getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle(app_name)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This
`builder.setAutoCancel(true);`

Answer (score 1):

If you set your notification to auto-cancel it is also removed once the user selects it.

**OR**

You can also call the cancel() for a particular notification ID to cancel notification.

```
notificationManager.cancel(notifyId);
```

Use this in the `MessageConversationActivity` class onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Use notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID); 
It cancel the notification id from the notification manager

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by using

```
Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

then start intent of page you want